# I have the idea of using the transitive property and/or the the integer combination property. I am stuck tho.

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, integers

\begin{equation}
a, b, \text { and } c \text { are integers. Prove that if } a |(b-1) \text { and } 5 a |(c+2), \text { then } a |(2 b+c)
\end{equation}

Comment: I have chosen the integers of 2 and 1 for the combination. can this work?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $5a|c+2$, then $a|c+2$ also (transitive property). Thus, because $a|b,c \implies a|b+c$ (integer combination property), we know  $a|2(b-1)+(c-2)=2b+c$ as required.

**Edit** added OP terminology to proof for clarity

Comment: The first sentence is not true. For $a=7$ and $c=3$: $5\cdot 7|3+2$ but not $7|3+2$.

Comment: @Hume2 That's not what | means; read it as "is a factor of"

Comment: Ah, sorry, I swapped the sides. You are right.

Comment: All good :) learn something (or refresh :P) new every day

Answer (score 0):

If $b-1=ka$ and $c+2=5ma$ then: $$2b+c=2(ka+1)+(5ma-2)=(2k+5m)a$$